# Flask positional argument self is missing but its not?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

When running my flask application I get the error

```
builtins.TypeError TypeError: get_task() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

In the browser when I go to 127.0.0.1/app/v1.0/test (default flask settings)

```
from flask import *
import json

class Server:
    app = Flask(__name__)

    def __init__(self, ip='', port=5000):
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port

    @app.route('/app/v1.0/<task>', methods=['GET'])
    def get_task(self, task):
        try:
            return task

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            abort(404)

    def run(self):
        self.app.run(debug=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    server = Server()
    server.run()
```

Comment: A flask app should not be contained in a class. Flask does not know how to call your function. It has no access to the `self` variable. The `app` variable and endpoints need to be a module scope, not class scope.

Comment: however, if you don't need to refer to the instance (`self`) in the method, you can declare it with only the argument `task`. Parameters are not passed by position but by name

Comment: I need to later use self because I plan on calling a function by its name from inside the server class. I feel like the tornado framework would be better suited for what I am doing.  How do I close this question and mark it answered?

Comment: It will be easier to manage what you need if you flatten all of this out of the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Flask App should not be nested in a class. I am switching to tornado as it better suites my needs.